# How to check share setting of gsheet by gspread

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-drive-api, gspread

I want to check owner share settings of gsheets by using gsperad as below.

[img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CYhdi.png)

Now I can get the share data by use `list_permissions(file_id)`  but I need more information about owner share settings by get True of False of Editors can change permissions and share and Viewers and commenters can see the option to download, print, and copy.

Thank you for your support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to manage "Viewers and commenters can see the option to download, print, and copy", `viewersCanCopyContent` is used.

In order to manage "Editors can change permissions and share", `writersCanShare` is used.

From this situation, in order to achieve your goal of `I want to check owner share settings of gsheets by using gsperad as below.`, it is required to confirm the values of `viewersCanCopyContent` and `writersCanShare` of the file.

When this is reflected in a sample script for gspread, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

```py
import gspread
from googleapiclient.discovery import build

spreadsheet_id = "###" # Please set your Spreadsheet ID.
client = gspread.oauth(###) # Please use your client of gspread.

service = build("drive", "v3", credentials=client.auth)
res = service.files().get(fileId=spreadsheet_id, fields="viewersCanCopyContent,writersCanShare").execute()
print(res)
```

- When this script is run, you can see the value of `{'viewersCanCopyContent': True, 'writersCanShare': True}`. Here, when `viewersCanCopyContent` is `True`, "Viewers and commenters can see the option to download, print, and copy" is checked. When `writersCanShare` is `True`, "Editors can change permissions and share" is checked.
- If you want to manage those values, please use "Files: update" method of Drive API.

#### Note:

- In this sample script, it supposes that you have already been able to get and put values to Google Spreadsheet using gspread for python. Please be careful about this.
- About `from googleapiclient.discovery import build`, please check [google-api-python-client](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client).

#### References:

- [Files: get](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/get)
- [Files: update](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/update?)

Comment: Hi Tanaike This script can get that my request Thanks. I have adjusted a bit for support multiple sheets and update value.